# Does Dataproc support Delta Lake format?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, databricks, google-cloud-dataproc, gcp-databricks

Is the Databricks Delta format available with Google's GCP DataProc?

For AWS and AZURE it is clear that this is so. However, when perusing, researching the internet, I am unsure that this is the case. Databricks docs less clear as well.

I am assuming Google feel their offerings are sufficient. E.g. Google Cloud Storage and is it mutable? This https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/getting-started/overview.html provides too little context.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use delta lake tables in GCP. You can add the delta-core JAR while creating dataproc cluster or when submitting a job then write and read delta format in GCS (`gs://...`) as you would do on the other platforms.

Comment: @blackbishop you can answer then, but I thought it was in preview still, thx

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/processing-databricks-delta-lake-data-in-google-cloud-dataproc-serverless-for-spark-1cc1405a3ee4

Comment: @AlexOtt thx for that, too old stuff on internet I suspect.

Comment: that's only 2 months old

Comment: @AlexOtt that delta supported on gcp you mean?

Comment: yes, if you start DataProc with necessary libraries, as @blackbishop mentioned

Comment: @AlexOtt  that's how do with HDP, just could not see the ref's but now we have

Comment: that article that I've put (google cloud medium) is explicitly about dataproc + delta lake on google storage

Comment: add answer @AlexOtt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta Lake format is supported on Dataproc. You can simply use it as any other data format such as Parquet and ORC. The following is an example from this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/processing-databricks-delta-lake-data-in-google-cloud-dataproc-serverless-for-spark-1cc1405a3ee4).

```
# Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from delta import *

def main():
    input = sys.argv[1]
    print("Starting job: GCS Bucket: ", input)
    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("DeltaTest")\
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")\
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")\
        .getOrCreate()
    data = spark.range(0, 500)
    data.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(input)
    df = spark.read \
    .format("delta") \
    .load(input)
    df.show()
    spark.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You also need to add the dependency when submitting the job with  `--properties="spark.jars.packages=io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.1.0"`.